# iphone - how to know the storage size an app used?

Tags: iphone, caching, core-data, size, diskspace

My app is caching content so that user can read it when offline.

I wrote everything of the cache into a database file (using CoreData) in iPhone.

However, the storage size is limited in iphone. So I would like to control the disk size my app is using.

How can I check the disk size I am using?

thanks

Comment: Can you just keep track of the cummulative bytes every time you save a file to the database file, or hardcore a checking method that fetches the size of the database each time something is about to be added to it - if it's less than your set limit then continue, else halt the operation?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The simplest and most accurate solution is to check the size of the persistent store directly.

Use `-[NSFileManager attributesOfItemAtPath:error:]` and then the `fileSize` key of the returned dictionary.